# Unable to communicate with proxy/server application

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, proxy

I am having issue with below code in TCP python socket prog. I am trying to send integer messages from (lets say) 3 clients. So, There is 3 clients, so the proxy knows that N = 3, and it will wait until it receives 3 numbers. 1st client sends 10 to the proxy, 2nd client sends 20 to the proxy, and the 3rd client sends 30 to the proxy. Because N is reached, the proxy starts to transmit to the server. It will send (in order): 10, 20, 30, END (where every comma indicates a new message). The server receives the 4 messages, and after receiving the END message, it starts to calculate the average. The average is 20, so the server sends 20 to the proxy, and closes the connection. The proxy receives 20, and sends it to all the 3 clients, and then closes the connection. The clients receive 20.

Please check below code and let me know where I am making mistake... I am able to send number from client but not getting response from proxy/server. Am I doing any mistake ?

For client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'

PORT = 21001

proxysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxysock.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    try:

         data = str(raw_input())
         except valueError:
         print 'invalid number'

   proxysock.sendall(data) 
   data = proxysock.recv(1024)
   print 'server reply:' +data
   proxysock.close()
```

For Proxy:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import select

  import sys

  import socket

  from thread import *

  HOST = 'localhost'

  PORT = 21001

  PORT1 = 22000


  max_conn = 5

  buffer_size = 2048

  proxyserversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

  proxyserversock.bind((HOST, PORT))

  proxyserversock.listen(max_conn)

 input = [proxyserversock,sys.stdin]

 running = 1 


 while running:

      inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])   
      for proxysock in inputready:
          if proxysock  == proxyserversock:
              client_sock, addr = proxyserversock.accept()
              input.append(client_sock)
          elif proxysock  == sys.stdin:
              junk = sys.stdin.readline()
              running = 0
          else:
              data = proxysock.recv(buffer_size)
          if data:
              proxysock.send(data)
          else:
              proxysock.close()
              input.remove(proxysock)                
      serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      serversock.connect((HOST, PORT1))

      serversock.sendall(data,END)

      serversock.recv(buffer_size)

      client_sock.sendall()

      serversock.close()    


      client_sock.close()
```

For Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket 

HOST = 'localhost'

PORT1 = 22000

serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

serversock.bind((HOST, PORT1))

serversock.listen(10) 

while 1:

     serversock, addr = serversock.accept() 

     data = serversock.recv(2048)
     data.pop()

     average = float(sum(data))/len(data)

     serversock.sendall(average)
     print 'avg' + average
     serversock.close()
```

Comment: @Maximilian Peters, thanks to edit. Can you tell if there is any problem in code

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you can fix your indentation (mixed tab/spaces, unclear which line belongs to which block), it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: I did that. Pls check

Comment: `File "client", line 15
    except valueError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`